# Return data from Dialog displayed to the user in Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case SORT_MENU:
        showDialog(ORDER_DIALOG);
        showDialog(COLUMNS_DIALOG);

        String orderBy = bundle.getString("column") + bundle.getString("order");

        break;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    final String[] columns = { "title", "completed" };
    final String[] order = { "Ascending", "Descending" };

    switch (id) {
    case COLUMNS_DIALOG:
        AlertDialog.Builder columnBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        columnBuilder.setTitle("Columns");
        columnBuilder.setItems(columns, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                bundle.putString("column", columns[which]);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog = columnBuilder.create();
        break;
    case ORDER_DIALOG:
        AlertDialog.Builder orderBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        orderBuilder.setTitle("Order");
        orderBuilder.setItems(order, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String orderS;
                if (order[which].equalsIgnoreCase("Ascending"))
                    orderS = "ASC";
                else
                    orderS = "DESC";

                bundle.putString("order", orderS);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog = orderBuilder.create();
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
        break;
    }

    return dialog;
}
```

I know that a Dialog is asynchronous from the main UI thread. So calls like these:

```
showDialog(ORDER_DIALOG);
showDialog(COLUMNS_DIALOG);
String orderBy = bundle.getString("column") + bundle.getString("order");
```

Only result in `orderBy` being null. Is there any way to have `orderBy` wait until both dialogs are confirmed to be finished? Even if `dialog.isShowing()` is false, this may be because the dialog has already finished or hasnt't even started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you must override and hook the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and, from its implementation, set the value of `orderBy`. In fact, this is a better aproach:

```
case SORT_MENU:
    showDialog(ORDER_DIALOG);
    break;
```

Then, on `onCreateDialog`:

```
case ORDER_DIALOG:
    AlertDialog.Builder orderBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    orderBuilder.setTitle("Order");
    orderBuilder.setItems(order, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String orderS;
            if (order[which].equalsIgnoreCase("Ascending"))
                orderS = "ASC";
            else
                orderS = "DESC";

            bundle.putString("order", orderS);
            dialog.dismiss();
            showDialog(COLUMNS_DIALOG); // <-- NEW!!!
        }
    });
    dialog = orderBuilder.create();
    break;
```

Again, on `onCreateDialog`:

```
case COLUMNS_DIALOG:
    AlertDialog.Builder columnBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    columnBuilder.setTitle("Columns");
    columnBuilder.setItems(columns, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            bundle.putString("column", columns[which]);
            dialog.dismiss();
            configureString(); // <-- NEW!
        }
    });
    dialog = columnBuilder.create();
    break;
```

Somewhere else:

```
private void configureString(){
    String orderBy = bundle.getString("column") + bundle.getString("order");
}
```